# Parsing JSON Files with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I'm new to C# so I don't know how JSON Parsing in C# much. So I'm using JSON.net at the moment, so this is what I got:

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
var data = c.DownloadString("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/furniture_items.json");
JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
button3.Text = "" + o["furniture_item_id"];
```

Is there any other way to parse JSON files with the JSON URL?

Comment: Well what's *wrong* with the code you've got? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: That code doesn't work: http://prntscr.com/39dmn7 http://prntscr.com/39dmr1

Comment: Rather than linking to screenshots, please include the error message *as text* within the question. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list for what makes a good question.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string getString =  client.DownloadString("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/furniture_items.json");


JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
var listOfFurniture = serializer.Deserialize<List<Furniture>>(getString);


public class Furniture
{
    public int furniture_item_id { get; set; }
}
```

There are many furniture_item_id's returned by the webclient. I've created a simple object that holds that value. 'listOfFurniture' is a List of type Furniture.

Comment: I'm sorry but how can I get "furniture_item_id" on the JSON file using this?

Comment: How can I get the ID? Like this: listOfFurniture[1]?

Comment: That would give you a Furniture object which will have a property named furniture_item_id.
So with listOfFurniture[0].furniture_item_id you would get the actual ID of the first piece of furniture in your JSON.

Comment: Thanks Alot Rasmus and gb1986!

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
```

You can then access `json` as array by using an index or a key:

```
var someval = json["furniture_item_id"];
```

**Note:**
In case the request was not successful and thus you do not have any response to parse, this will probably end up in an `JsonParseException` so you might want to catch that.